# Does a kernel driver get loaded before device tree parsing

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, startup, modprobe, device-tree

When a device tree is getting processed by the kernel on startup, does the kernel load its correct device driver there and then, or it must already be loaded?

Let's take a special I2C device for example. It is described in the device tree, such as its I2C address, compatibility etc. and the kernel is able to determine which device driver it should use. Does the kernel then load the driver using modprobe or something similar?